# How to remove brackets in the email claim from Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to remove the brackets in the `email` claims that I getfrom Azure AD B2C.

After the user logs in I decode user's token and get the email from that. But the email that I get has brackets in it. The email looks like this `["email@email.com"]` which its make it ugly when I save it to the database.

Is there some setting to remove the brackets from the email claim?

```
JObject ParseIdToken(string idToken)
{
    // Get the piece with actual user info
    idToken = idToken.Split('.')[1];
    idToken = Base64UrlDecode(idToken);
    return JObject.Parse(idToken);
}

private string Base64UrlDecode(string s)
{
    s = s.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
    s = s.PadRight(s.Length + (4 - s.Length % 4) % 4, '=');
    var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
    var decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Count());
    return decoded;
}

public  void CacheUser(AuthenticationResult ar)
{
    JObject user = ParseIdToken(ar.IdToken);
    var cache = new CachedUsers
    {
        FullName = user["name"]?.ToString(),
        Email = user["emails"]?.ToString()

    };
     BlobCache.LocalMachine.InsertObject("usercached", cache);
}
```

That is my code to get the email. Why does the email have brackets? I guess the problem is not in my code but maybe there is some setting in Azure AD B2C that makes it like that because when I try to decode the token from https://jwt.io/ it returns the same, the email with brackets. Has anyone experienced this?

Here is the payload from jwt.io [image]

You can see the difference between name and the email. The email has brackets like this `[ ]` and what I want to know is how to remove those brackets and make it like name. Because when I get the email in Xamarin forms it has those brackets too so instead of `emailname@gmail.com`  it get like this `["emailname@gmail.com"]`

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you are saying. Can you share a sample token and call out what you'd expect to see different in it?

Comment: i update my question, can you figure this out thanks

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: user["emails"]?.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JSON, brackets denote arrays. See this basic [JSON Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) documentation.

While not easily exposed via the Azure AD B2C UI, it's technically possible for a user to have multiple emails linked to their account, which is why the email claim is an array.

The reason the string you are seeing is shown as `["user@email.com"]` is because you are calling `.ToString()` on a JSON array. You need to modify your code to obtain a specific element of that array, for example, the first element:

```cs
public  void CacheUser(AuthenticationResult ar)
{
    JObject user = ParseIdToken(ar.IdToken);
    var cache = new CachedUsers
    {
        FullName = user["name"]?.ToString(),
        Email = user["emails"]?.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString()
    };
     BlobCache.LocalMachine.InsertObject("usercached", cache);
}
```